# Small business shredder with autofeeding capabilities?

Tags: office

A small business I do work for does a lot of paper shredding. Currently, each employee has their own personal shredder near their desk. The employees and owners have complained that the shredding is time consuming. They need to feed the paper - usually 3-4 sheets at time - into the shredder, wait for it to complete and then repeat. Each time they start shredding, they have a stack of paper much larger than 3-4 sheets, so it takes time for this process to complete.

The owners would like to replace the individual shredders with one or two office shredders. The idea is that users will be able to drop a stack of 100-200 sheets into a feeding tray and the shredder will ingest them automatically. The user will not have to sit and baby sit the machine during a shredding cycle.

Requirements:

- Should be able to handle 100 sheets of paper at a time
- Should have a large enough bin to collect more than one full batch of 100 shredded papers (this way the next user doesn't have to empty the container first)
- Should slice the paper into small diamonds, not single long strands of paper
- Shredder to be able to be fitted with a plastic garbage bag, but also needs to be easily emptied if such a bag isn't fitted
- Should be durable. There will be at least 4,000 sheets of paper shredded per work week

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to computer hardware or even electronics in any way.

Comment: Thinking about it, you are both correct. A shredder is really automatic only in the sense that it detects if paper is present. It's a simple on/off machine. I'll vote to close

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Rexel [Auto Feed Micro Cut series](http://www.rexeleurope.com/en/gb/5967/auto-feed-micro-cut#.VfXHfPlVikq) seems right for you.

It's a series of shredders, ranging from the 100M (which takes 100 sheets at 80gsm) up to the 750M (which takes 750 sheets at 80gsm).

On your requirements:

- Any of the series can handle 100 sheets
- I can't actually tell how big the bins are relative to the load, but they look big enough to take more than one load
- Doesn't cut diamonds, but does cut each sheet into "2000 2 x 15 mm bits"
- You can probably put a bag inside the bin and mount the shredder to keep it in place, if that works for you
- Rexel make good quality stuff; their website doesn't say durability stats but I'd imagine they're pretty high.